# Telegram bot get forward_from user id

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I'm trying to get the id of a user whose message has been forwarded. Like Message forwarded from X and I need to get X id

I tried with this but I don't receive anything about forward_from

```
<?php
$update = file_get_contents('php://input');
$update = json_decode($update, TRUE);
$message = isset($update['message']) ? $update['message'] : "";
$reply = isset($message['reply_to_message']) ? $message['reply_to_message'] : "";
$reply_id_username = isset($reply['forward_from']['id']) ? $reply['forward_from']['id'] : "";
```

$reply result is

```
{
    "message_id": 3,
    "from": {
        "id": BOT ID,
        "is_bot": true,
        "first_name": "X",
        "username": "X_Bot"
    },
    "chat": {
        "id": MY ID,
        "first_name": "Me",
        "username": "Me",
        "type": "private"
    },
    "date": 1590679285,
    "forward_sender_name": "User X",
    "forward_date": 1590679285,
    "text": "Text"
}
```

It gives to me just his name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During forwarding the returned [message](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) object only provides `forward_sender_name` (text with sender's name) if the user does not allow including the account information with the forwarded message. It is controlled by the [Privacy Policy](https://telegram.org/blog/unsend-privacy-emoji#anonymous-forwarding)

If profile sharing is enabled this information should be available in `forward_from` field of the `Message`